# How to create a maven archetype with both inherited and aggregated modules?

Tags: java, maven

I am using `mvn archetype:create-from-project` within a manually created project

This project has both inherited and aggregated modules.
However when creating a new project based on this fresh archetype, the aggregated module pom file always finds itself injected with `<parent>..</parent>` attribute thus inheriting rather than being aggregated, which screws up the build order.

How can I prevent this aggregated module to be injected with `<parent>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not possible.

There's an open request for it on their JIRA from November 2011:

> As mentioned in ARCHETYPE-110, the current implementation overwrites parent information if there are no existing parent definition inside the body of the pom.xml. So if we don't want such declaration we haven't no alternatives.

Source: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-393